# Python, If statement error with variables says not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, kivy, kivymd

I am having a problem when I am trying to use the if statement in python.
I cannot see if a variable is true or false because it says the variable is not defined but I defined it in a method.

I am using kivy and kivyMD as well, just in case people were wondering why some of the code was there.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def show_data(self):
        inputFahrenheit = self.root.ids.fahrenheit.text
        if fahrenheit1 is True:
            Celsius_Half = float(inputFahrenheit) - 32 
            Celsius_Before_Round = Celsius_Half * 5/9

            Celsius = round(Celsius_Before_Round , 1)

    def convert1F(self):
        fahrenheit1 = True
        celsius1 = False

    def convert1C(self):
        fahrenheit1 = False
        celsius1 = True

    def convert2F(self):
        fahrenheit2 = True
        celsius2 = False

    def convert2C(self):
        fahrenheit2 = False
        celsius2 = True

    def on_start(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv") 
        screen = Screen()
        return kv
            
    
DemoApp().run()
```

The if statement is the problem there is a copy of the problem:
`"fahrenheit1" is not defined`

Comment: Functions are variable namespaces. Local variables are only valid inside them. What you need inside your methods should be attached to `self` and initialized in `__init__()`.

Comment: It says `"fahrenheit1" is not defined`because "fahrenheit1" is not defined. First, it seems to be defined inside your "convertxx()" methods. Then even there, they are local variables (limited to there function's scope).

Comment: If's not the `if` statement. The variable `fahrenheit1` and its friends are local to the methods you have defined. They disappear after the method returns and are not visible outside the method. That is why you get the `NameError`.

Comment: ...if you want to use `fahrenheit1` and friends in the methods you have to declare them in the class like `self.fahrenheit1`, etc.

Comment: Can someone tell me step by step what to do because I am a bit new to programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order for `fahrenheit1` to be defined, you need to declare it as a class attribute.
Either define in in the class `__init__` or as a static attribute at the top of the class, outside of any method) as `fahrenheit1: bool = <your_defualt_value>`

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no defined variable called fahrenheit1.
Fix that first